# Equivocal meaning of "Have a backlog of (something)"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Isn't there an equivocal sense to saying "I have a backlog of (something)"?

> I have a backlog of work and would be unable to help you out on that.
>
> I have a few outfits that I haven't shot yet -- have to keep up or there will be an unwanted backlog of outfits since September.[source](http://www.pandaphilia.com/2010/11/bringing-sexy-back.html)
>
> I have a backlog of fruits that have been sitting in the bottom of the fridge for a couple of weeks now -- have to eat them now or else they are going to spoil!
>
> My main reason for making yogurt this week, though, was that I had a growing backlog of milk in the fridge.[source](http://www.tomaytotomaaahto.com/2011/02/making-yogurt.html)
>
> My main reason for eating a stick of butter every day, though, was that I had a backlog of these sitting in the bottom of the freezer.

vs.

> I have a backlog of work which will keep myself, my designer and my technician busy all through the fall.
>
> I have an unexpected backlog of cash which should keep my family and myself safe from necessity in these times of hardship.
>
> Some states have an unexpected backlog of money which will enable them to award new grants[source](http://digitool.library.colostate.edu/webclient/DeliveryManager?pid=12489)
>
> Some colleges and universities have an unexpected backlog of money which will enable them to catch up on the longstanding housing shortage.
>
> I have an unexpected backlog of cash this year. I'm going to buy a Porsche!

Please also consider these links:

- http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/backlog
- https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/backlog
- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backlog
- http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backlog

Comment: What do you think 'backlog' means in each case?

Comment: The usual sense is that of something that _has_ to be dealt with: an accumulation of something, esp. uncompleted work or matters that need to be dealt with. [Google]

Comment: Based upon our conversation below, I would recommend you revise this question to include the usage about food and other items.  It might help you.

Comment: The latest revision makes your point easier to understand.  Good work!

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of "have a backlog" in both cases is exactly the same: "have a backlog". The bad news vs. good news difference comes from the words *thankfully* and *unfortunately*.

This works for any and all expressions, not just this one.

- > Unfortunately, it's raining cats and dogs.
  >   Thankfully, it's raining cats and dogs.
- > Unfortunately, I own a big house.
  >   Thankfully, I own a big house.
- > Unfortunately, I am getting older.
  >   Thankfully, I am getting older.
- > Unfortunately, I am unemployed.
  >   Thankfully, I am unemployed.
- > Unfortunately, I am a mass murderer.
  >   Thankfully, I am a mass murderer.

Comment: I suppose it could be either good or bad that's it's raining cats and dogs if you're an ageing, unemployed mass murderer living in a big house…

Comment: It's actually entertaining and not too difficult to put the "unexpected" versions of those sentences into a meaningful context :) "Oh, you are afraid about me stealing your money? No need to worry, I am a mass murderer, not a thief!"

Comment: @RegDwigHt Sorry to have to disagree with you on that. If you check back the meaning of "backlog" online, you'll see for yourself that what generally prevails is the definition  "a quantity of work that should have been done already, but has not yet been done, and have to be dealt with", which undoubtedly has a negative connotation to it. If I intentionally picked examples starting with "thankfully" and "hopefully", it's mostly for convenience purposes, but also to make the difference more apparent. Please consider these links: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backlog

Comment: @RegDwigHt http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backlog http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/backlog.asp http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/backlog http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/backlog http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/backlog

Comment: I am not seeing where you are going with this. "Mass murderer" obviously has a negative connotation, too. All examples I provided have a default connotation. That is the very reason I included them.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Wait, wait, wait . . . Mass murderer has a *negative* connotation, too?  ;-)  Hahahahahahahaha!  As oerkelens points out, you could easily create a sentence that it works for.  My conscience could easily have been bothered by being asked to assassinate the President of Guatamala.  Thankfully, I am a mass murderer and beyond such petty emotions.  Hahahahahahaha!

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Reg is right here.  Backlog, while normally holding a negative connotation, can be applied to a  beneficial situation as well.  Think of it as, "Thankfully I broke my leg, because I missed the avalanche at the ski resort."  The person is saying, well, I might have lost the business, but I have a lot on my plate as it is.  You wouldn't put the word backlog into an investors report, though.  Think of it as a consolation prize and you will get the gist here.

Comment: @DavidM What I want to point up with this is that -- according to FOD and to other dictionary online -- there are two distinctly opposite meanings to "backlog": one is an accumulations of things that haven't been done already and have to be taken care of; two is a reserve supply or source, something kept back or saved for future use or a special purpose. For instance, if I say (context unbeknownst) "I have a backlog of grass-fed butter in the freezer" -- depending on the tone -- this can mean...

Comment: @DavidM I have a nice supply of grassfed butter in the freezer, and so it's quite unlikely I'll run out of that stuff pretty soon". But, it also can mean: "I still have quite a lot of butter in the freezer that is waiting to be eaten, so I should seriously think about that". ;)

Comment: @NourishedGourmet No, backlog would be a strange usage to convey that point.  You would use the word *surplus* in that context.  You should probably change the question to reflect your real intent, you will get a better answer.

Comment: @DavidM Done! ;)

Comment: @Nourished - I'm afraid I'm confused. I checked your link, here was the definition: "an accumulation of tasks unperformed or materials not processed." How is that "undoubtably negative?" Consider: _Two years ago, they were on the brink of closing this plant. Now we have a backlog of orders._ That sounds positive to me, particularly if you work at the plant, like your job, and were scared of becoming unemployed. If Reg is wrong, I don't think I get your point.

Comment: @J.R. OAD -- just to name one among others -- defines "backlog" as a quantity of work that should be done already, but has not yet been done(=work in arrears which should preferably be dealt with at one's earliest), and gives as an example: "When she eventually returned to work, there was a tremendous backlog of paperwork to catch up on". I don't know for you, but -- even without specifying that it's a tremendous one -- it would sound like bad news to me. Hence the negative connotation. :)

Comment: @J.R. What I'm trying to point up here is that there is an equivocal sense to the term "backlog" since it can have either a negative connotation: a significant amount of things that have been left undone or anything and should be taken care of ASAP; or a positive connotation (a comfortable reserve/supply of something).

Comment: @J.R. "Backlog" in your example conveys the idea of a nice supply, a comfortable reserve of orders that should keep the plant safe from closing.

Comment: Well, which is it? [Undoubtably negative](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155179/equivocal-meaning-of-have-a-backlog-of-something/155180#comment322623_155180)? Or [negative or positive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155179/equivocal-meaning-of-have-a-backlog-of-something/155180#comment322852_155180)? If the latter, RegDwight has summarized it quite nicely; **context** will determine which is intended.

Comment: By the way, "backlog" in my example could convey a multiplicity of ideas all at once. Business is good, the plant is no longer in danger of closing, but the workers are bustling, and management may be stressed. The "reserve of orders" you mention may be "comfortable" from a layoff perspective, but the worker in the warehouse destined to be late for his 7PM dinner reservation might describe it very differently.

Answer (score 3):

*Based upon our conversation in comments:*

**Backlog** conveys a sense of unfinished *tasks* that need to be completed.  As Reg states below, it does carry a mildly negative connotation that can be modified situationally.  I won't reiterate his excellent answer here.

If you are speaking of unused *items or goods*, you would use the term **surplus**.

**Surplus** means an amount or quantity greater than needed.  [Definition link here.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surplus)

If you want to convey a sense that this is a negative, you would say:  **unwanted surplus**.

> If you'll excuse me, I have a backlog of unfinished reports to get to.

vs.

> I have an *unwanted surplus* of goat cheese.  It is going to rot before I can sell it!
>   or
>   I have an unexpected *surplus* of cash this year, I'm going to  buy a Ferrari!

I think this fits the meaning you are looking for far better than *backlog*.